# Reset child angular component called from a parent component that it's a modal window

Tags: angular, components, lifecycle

I have an angular child component which parent component it's a modal window (I'm using ngx-smart-modal for implementing the modals). When the modal window its closed using the method:

```
this.ngxSmartModalService.getModal('ModalNameComponent').close();
```

in fact the modal is not destroyed but just become hidden. How can I notify the child component that the modal was closed. Does anyone have any idea? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this in my modals with a different external library is to have an event emitter on the child that the parent binds to. (This is pure Angular, and nothing to do with which external library is used).

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() close: EventEmitter<void> = new Event<Emitter>();

  // method is called from the child - maybe from a button click in your html
  onClose(): void {
    this.close.emit();
  }
}
```

Parent:

```
<app-child-component *ngIf="showModal" (close)="showModal=false">
</app-child-component>
```